# C++ type lists with its alias in the list

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a list of types in C++ that contains its alias in the list?

I would like to achieve something like:

```
using MyList = TypeList<int, float, MyList>;
```

Comment: That would be an infinite recursion, to what type should the compiler resolve that list? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anedar I would like to use an std::variant that has itself as one of the options.

Comment: What would you gain? If you had a variant holding (int or float or (int or float or (int or float or ...))) it would still be only int or float in it....

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Your real question is probably better than this.

Comment: @Anedar I could build a tree out of it as only one option is viable at run time.

Comment: Maybe try something with `std::type_index` and a `std::map` to a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,  it is not possible because

> type alias is a name that *refers to a previously defined type* (similar to `typedef`).

This refers to `using`.

From here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: :)  you asked if it's possible, I've answerd based on my knowledge, that is not possible. Maybe someone else knows a tip and trick.

Comment: I will leave this question open for a while, maybe somebody has some interesting workaround. If not, I will accept your answer

Comment: @Felics Unlikely because no one really knows what you actually want to solve by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

While mtb's answer is certainly the correct answer to your question, from the comments i guess what you are looking for is something like this:

```
class variantTree{
    public:

    std::variant<int,float> v;
    std::unique_ptr<variantTree> child=nullptr;

};
```

While a class might not have a member of its own type (infinite recursion again), it might have a pointer to another object of the same type.

With appropriate setters and getters and possibly test functions if its a node or a value you should be able to create a tree. However you might have to recreate some of the functionality that a variant provides for you by default.

Comment: Probably this is the way to go, although I would go for std::optional to avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Felics: What would be the size of `VariantTree` with `optional` ?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers well explainted what can be done, however it is possible to create tree of types(nested type), but depth of tree should be obtained at compile time.
leaf node may be an empty TypeList i.e. TypeList<> or other things, two of them commented in the code:

```
template <typename...Ts>
struct TypeList{};

template <size_t Depth, typename...Ts>
struct TypeTreeGenerator {
    template <typename...Ks>
    using type =  TypeList<Ts...,typename  TypeTreeGenerator<Depth-1, Ts..., Ks...>::template type<>>;
};

template <typename...Ts>
struct TypeTreeGenerator<0, Ts...> {
    template <typename...Ks>
    using type =  TypeList<>;
//possible other implementations:
//    using type =  TypeList<Ts..., Ks..., void>; 
// OR...
//    using type =  TypeList<Ts..., Ks...>;
};

template<size_t Depth, typename...Ts> 
    using TypeTree = typename TypeTreeGenerator<Depth, Ts...>::template type<>;
```

this example creates a nested TypeList of depth 5:

```
TypeTree<5, int , float> tree;
```